# Filtering Spark SQL dataframe for distance

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, geopy

I have a Spark SQL `DataDrame` with columns latitude and longitude, I am trying to filter rows that fall below a threshold by calculating the distance to an input. My current code looks like. I am using `geopy` (`great_circle`) for calculating the distance between lat long pairs.

```
from geopy.distance import great_circle

point = (10, 20)
threshold = 10
filtered_df = df.filter(great_circle(point, (df.lat, df.lon)) < threshold)
```

When I run this code I get the following error

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

I am confused on which part of the filter expression is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply plain Python functions on a `DataFrame`. You have to use `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf("float")
def great_circle_udf(x, y):
    return great_circle(x, y).kilometers
```

and apply it with columns

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, struct

point = struct(lit(10), lit(20))
df.filter(great_circle_udf(point, struct(df.lat, df.lon)) < threshold))
```

Decorator syntax will work since 2.2, for earlier version you'll need standard `udf` call:

```
udf(great_circle, FloatType())
```